# Carrot2 documents similarity and how are the ordered documents indexes in the tf-idf matrix?

Tags: matrix, indexing, document, documents, carrot2

I'm trying to determine the similarity between two documents using carrot. Is it possible get this similarity directly from the framework?

Additionally I've been studying the tf-idf matrix and realized that the rows correspond to the stemmed all words and columns to documents. However, how can I identify which document corresponds to which column?

For example, suppose a list of documents, the column order will be the order of the documents in the list?

Ex:

List docs = {doc1, doc2, doc3}

and

Column 0 = doc1
Coluns 1 = doc2

...

Is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carrot2 does not use the conventional notion of document-document similarity, so you won't find it there. You can indeed use the term-document matrix to compute all sorts of document-document similarity.

You are correct in assuming that the columns of the term-document matrix are in the same order as the documents in the input list. You can check the [source code](https://github.com/carrot2/carrot2/blob/master/core/carrot2-util-text/src/org/carrot2/text/vsm/TermDocumentMatrixBuilder.java) to clear any other doubts.